# Push notification to all the users subscribed to the topic except login user using FCM Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Now i have a group which have more than ten thousand members and for a group i have created a topic(Notification topic) where all the users in the group subscribed to that topic. Now inside the group any user can add post like image or file or video. When user add the post i need to send notification to all the users subscribed to that topic but except one, that is person who add the post. How can i achieve this??

Now notification is going to all the users including the person who add the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no parameter of any sort to exclude a specific user from receiving a message from a topic they are subscribed to. However, as a workaround, you could simply have a custom implementation on building the payload and handling the message to receive it.

Depending on how you build your payload, you could just add a custom key-value pair that includes the user id of the one who posted the data (something like `posterId` or simply `userId`).

Then on your client side, when handling the push notification, just check if the id is the user's or not. If it is the same user, don't show the notification, else show it. e.g.:

```
if (userId == currentUserId) {
    // if user is the one that sent the message, don't show the notification
    return;
}
```

Comment: Like this can we avoid to show the notification in notification tray itself for that user??

Comment: If you're using a `data`-*only* message payload, it's possible. But if you have the `notification` parameter, then no (when your app is in background, the Android system automatically handles the `notification` message). What I mentioned is just a sample to provide the idea on how to go around it. I think there are still other ways to get around this.

Comment: You're welcome. Also have a look at [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). Depending on this use-case, it might be useful. :)

Comment: I am wondering how to send the "most read article" to a topic but exclude those users who already seen / read it ? Do I need to keep list of read articles on the client side ? If thats the case it might not work when the app is not launched.

Comment: @abiieez I think that is solved better by having a filter on the ids prior to adding them to the topic. Check if userId has read the topic before (I assume you have a list per user), true = don't add, false = add. Then unsubscribe as necessary.

Comment: Looks like unsubsribe and subcribe back is way of tackling This issue. Thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question is already answered and a bit old, there's a workaround. So therefore I will still add the answer for future reference. What you can do is unsubscribe the user from the topic, send the message to the topic and subscribe the user once again. Sure that is a bit more work and calls to Firebase, but then you've got what you want.

Just a thought

Comment: Works for me: Just don't forget to add some few seconds before you subscribe back incase of slow networks

    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), (){
        firebaseMesseging.subscribeToTopic("POST");
      });

Comment: @Erik Dohmen For unscribing the user, we need registration token of the app instance and for example if the user is using multiple devices then we need to get all the registration tokens of the user and then call unssubscribeTopic() on all tokens. so for this we need to store all the tokens in a database. Then it might be very difficult to manage tokens(stored in database). Is there anyway to do it without managing this token on application server?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the "unsubscribe" has time to work before the message is sent...? Or would I need to add a few seconds there as well? Coz that'd be annoying...