# How to exclude device from firebase topic messaging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ok. Let's make this simple.

I've a topic say `A`, where 3 devices subscribed to it, say `D1`, `D2` and `D3`.

Now, when I fire a message to topic `A`, I want to exclude `D1` from the list, so that `D1` won't get that specific notification.

**Questions :**

1. Is it possible to do ? If yes, how can I do that ?
2. Is there any workaround ?

I've read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging), but can't find any helpful information or APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to exclude a specific device when sending to a topic.

The best I can think of is to send a data message, and suppress displaying it on the relevant client(s). I now notice that is what AL answered before, so I'll close your question as a dupe against this: [Push notification to all the users subscribed to the topic except login user using FCM Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406256/push-notification-to-all-the-users-subscribed-to-the-topic-except-login-user-usi)

Comment: Thank your for your time frank. :)

Comment: Does this still hold true?

Comment: Nothing has changed in this respect.