# Firebase messaging topics, logic

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Lets say users subscribe to a topic, checkedIn_"restaurantId", meaning they (and I) gets notified when users check in at the restaurant with that id.

But, I want to avoid to get notified when I (myself) checks in to that restaurant.

How would one manage that?

I only see one way out: I unsubscribe from that topic, then sending message, then subscribe again.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to exclude on user from a notification to a topic. The common way to implement is to separate message delivery, from the display of the notification on the device.

If you send a `data` only message with Firebase Cloud Messaging, it is *always` the responsibility of your application code to handle that message. So if you send the information about the check-in in a data-only message and include the ID of the user in that data, the receiving code can check whether that is their own message and *not* display a notification in that case.

To learn more, see:

- the documentation about [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)
- [Push notification to all the users subscribed to the topic except login user using FCM Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406256/push-notification-to-all-the-users-subscribed-to-the-topic-except-login-user-usi)
- [How to exclude device from firebase topic messaging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588217/how-to-exclude-device-from-firebase-topic-messaging/53588719#53588719)