# How can I exclude a certain device from Firebase cloud messaging topic notification groups

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-notifications

I have successfully implemented Firebase Topic messaging and I am getting notifications successfully to all the subscribed devices.
But now the problem is, I am even getting notification when I am sending message myself(As I am subscribed to the topic).
What should I do that I do not receive topic message when I myself send a message?

I have tried the following-

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(Rxusrnm); //TEMPORARY UNSUBSCRIPTION
sendMessageNotification("New Messsage from group :"+ Rxusrnm,message,is_group_chat);
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Rxusrnm);
```

which is not working..
what approach should I follow?

Comment: There is no way to exclude a specific device from a topic. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406256/push-notification-to-all-the-users-subscribed-to-the-topic-except-login-user-usi

Comment: my code for temporary purpose may not be good to use, but it seems to work,I will update the answer if I am satisfied with testing with my given code prove to be successful @FrankvanPuffelen - is there any possible backdrop of that code?

Comment: If the code works for you use-case, then go for it.